# How to get ItemTappedEventArgs with EventToCommandBehavior in Prism for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Xamarin.Forms and Prism 6.3.0

It seems that I'm unable to get the ItemTappedEventArgs (or the sender object which is the ListView) by using the EventToCommandBehavior.

In my XAML, I have the 2 namespace defined

```
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Prism.Converters;assembly=Prism.Forms"
```

also in my XAML, in my ListView I have the following

```
<ListView.Behaviors>
    <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" 
         EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource ItemTappedEventArgsConverter}"/>
</ListView.Behaviors>
```

In my ViewModel I declare my DelegateCommand

```
public DelegateCommand<object> ItemTappedCommand { get; set; }
```

I assign the command in the constructor of the ViewModel

```
ItemTappedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(ItemTapped);
```

and then I implement the command

```
void ItemTapped(object args)
{
...
}
```

I also have defined elsewhere in the code "MyApp/Converters" the `ItemTappedEventArgsConverter` that is proposed in the documentation.

The application (Android) show the usual "Application stopped working" message, before even start.

I was able to use the `CommandParameter="MyParameter"` instead of the `EventArgsConverter` in XAML and also I was able to get info from the item by using the `EventArgsParameterPath="Item"`

But the moment that I use the `EventArgsConverter`, I get the error and the application doesn't start.

What I'm doing wrong? How to get the args (or the sender) in the event behavior? Is there an example that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. Actually there were 2 problems.

The first is the reference of the assembly that contains the converter.
Instead of

`xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Prism.Converters;assembly=Prism.Forms"`

it should be

`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Converters"`

(or whatever is the name of the assembly that contains the converter)

The second mistake is that I didn’t have the following XAML in my content page

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ItemTappedEventArgsConverter x:Key="ItemTappedEventArgsConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```